# VBSript Shutdown Message Confusion

Tags: windows, vba, vbscript

I am currently learning how to write commands in Visual Basic and decided to make a simple shutdown message. The code worked perfectly: when the user clicked 'yes' it shutdown and 'no', 'cancel' and the 'X' button closed the message.
However, I decided to try a make a prank message aswell, where the computer would shutdown whatever option was chosen. I ran the script, however when I clicked the 'X' icon (I did not fancy the idea of shutting down *my* computer!), my computer shutdown anyway :(
Is there a way to stop this happening, or, even better, is there a way to grey out the 'X' icon so the user cannot close the message?
Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim result
result = MsgBox ("Do you want to shutdown?", 3+48,"Warning")
Dim objShell
Select Case result
    Case vbYes
        MsgBox("shuting down ...")
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 20"
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox("shuting down ...")
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 20"
    Case vbCancel
        MsgBox("shuting down ...")
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 20"
End Select
```

Cheers in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, is there a reason for trying to remove/disable the X? I ask because it will be kinda difficult though it can be done.

1. Not all button combinations on the msgbox enable the X. Try vbAbortRetryIgnore and also try vbYesNo.
2. If a Cancel button is provided (all other combinations except vbOkOnly) then X is enabled
3. If only one button is displayed then X is enabled

This really makes it almost pointless to disable the button once you are aware of these things. Here's what happens when the above scenarios are displayed an user hits X vs clicking on a button

1. N/A. X button not enabled
2. MsgBox returns vbCancel
3. MsgBox returns value of only button
   By the way, it is not just clicking X. When X is enabled, ESC will trigger same results.

Answer (score 1):

**-r : for reboot**

**-s : for shutdown**

This Vbscript can create a shortcut on your desktop asking you if you want to shutdown the computer or not.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyScriptPath 
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"Shutdown the computer")
Call AskQuestion()
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,Name)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If Name = "" Then
        Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-28"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,Msg,Title
    Title = "Shutdown the computer"
    Msg = "Are you sure to shutdown the computer now ?"& Vbcr &_
    "If yes, then click [YES] button "& Vbcr &_
    "If not, then click [NO] button"
    Question = MsgBox (Msg,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Run_Shutdown(30)
    else
        WScript.Quit()
    End if
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Run_Shutdown(N)
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Save your work because your PC will shut down in "& N &" seconds")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies! The problem is now solved :)